# Simple TextView causes crash

Tags: android

It's very simple code but when I initialize the `TextView`, the app just crashes.

I'm a beginner, so I don't know if I made something wrong.... but in my opinion the code looks fine. Android Studio doesn't report any errors either.

```
int counterint = 0;
TextView counter = findViewById(R.id.countertv);

public void pressthebutton(View view){
    counterint++;
    counter.setText(counterint);
}
```

Comment: what is you error code ? share your xml

Comment: Please add your crash stack trace to the question

Comment: Also setText won't allow to set int value, you need to use `Integer.toString(counterInt)` for conversion

Comment: Very well noticed @Astha

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Astha Thank you, that solves my next (and last) error! It works now, thanks to everyone!

Comment: You could use something like this too, also would solve your problems by now cause the int would be "converted" into a string: `counter.setText(counterint + "");`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably setting the `TextView` during the class instantiation. You should update your code as follows:

```
int counterint = 0;
TextView counter;

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(<your_layout>);

    // Set the textView only after setContent.. Otherwise, findViewById will return null
    counter = findViewById(R.id.countertv);
}


public void pressthebutton(View view){
    counterint++;
    counter.setText(Integer.toString(counterInt));
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer.. As  Astha mentioned, you can't set an interger direcly via setText(counterInt).. You must call setText(Integer.toString(counterInt)) to convert the int to String

Answer (score 0):

try setting your textview this way :

```
public void pressthebutton(View view){
    counterint++;
    counter.setText(String.valueOf(counterInt));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error causes because you directly assign an integer value to the TextView. It is good to convert an integer or any data type to String when you assigning it to the TextView

```
int counterint = 0;
TextView counter = findViewById(R.id.countertv);

public void pressthebutton(View view){
    counterint++;
    counter.setText(Integer.toString(counterint));
}
```

otherview you can convert the Integer value to string first and then assign it to the TextView as follows

```
int counterint = 0;
TextView counter = findViewById(R.id.countertv);
String counterString = Integer.toString(counterint)

public void pressthebutton(View view){
    counterint++;
    counter.setText(counterString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
counter.setText(counterint+"");
```

It automatically set the string value to `textview`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
public void pressthebutton(View view){
    counter.setText(String.valueOf(++counterint));
}
```